# Xamarin. Парсинг excel файла

Tags: c#, парсер, xamarin, mobile-development

Пишу приложение для дипломки, которое должно парсить excel файл с расписанием пар колледжа и раскидывать его по нужным ячейкам во вкладках групп. Не могу написать парсер, в интернете искал, но никакой толковой инфы я не нашел, скорее всего я плохо искал. Если есть источник с инструкцией как это сделать, пожалуйста поделитесь, или библиотеки с помощью которых это можно реализовать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Верно, плохо искали https://stackoverflow.com/q/151005/12888024